# Javascript with larger projects with SignalR and KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I am curious to find out how other teams work with Javascript within their projects.  Currently I have a MVC .Net app - using a service-oriented architecture with Entity framework.. blah blah blah - not really what I am trying to ask but useful to know.  For the client side, I am using signalr with knockout.  Knockout needs to you bind a view model and then SignalR gets involved and it gets fun.

To split this up (and to get all the dependencies Knockout, jQuery, etc) I decided to use RequireJS and structured it like this:

```
|- \Js
   |- app.js (This actually creates a connection with signalr)
   |- config.js (requirejs.config - lists all the js libraries and then lists their dependancies)
   | - \App
       |- SomeFunction.js (Initialises the viewmodel and binds to the view)
       |- \ViewModel
          |- SomeViewModel.js (Consists of the view model)
          |- SomeOtherViewModel.ks (You get the idea...)
```

(I've not listed the libraries but they are listed in a vendor folder within the Js folder)

The reason why I split the files up so much is because 1000+ lines of javascript is really hard to read plus it makes it easier for my team to work on different elements of the project. But this does come with a downside - when I look at the amount of traffic there is per request, its 1.5mb which doesn't sound that bad but as the javascript files grow it is becoming an increasing problem (particularly as I promised the application would be faster!)

I've tried to use minified versions of the vendor libraries but this really doesn't make much of an impact.  Has anyone come across this problem, and how did you overcome this?  I am not sure how I can minfiy the javascript (without doing this manually) and still use requirejs to manage the dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize your code by using RequireJS' `r.js` [optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). The optimizer knows how to optimize RequireJS modules. It can be configured to leave vendor stuff intact. Look into the documentation of `r.js`, try it, and ask more questions if you run into specific problems. There's no one-size-fits-all answer to how to use it.

By using the optimizer you can significantly reduce the number of network requests and the size of the data transfered. It was significant enough in one of the apps I'm developing that before I used the optimizer I got test timeouts when running Selenium tests on a remote server farm. The timeouts disappeared after optimization.

Comment: I had considered this but I am not sure how I am going to include this within my build process.  Did you separate out javascript build process from your project build process?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is your question closely tied to how .Net projects are structured and built? I use ``make`` to build my stuff and I've only built it in Linux. Since day 1 I've had a target named ``build/standalone`` that would combine my code with external code into a single tree of JS code. For optimization purposes, I've added a ``build/standalone-optimized`` target to run ``r.js`` on the files in ``build/standalone`` so as to create an optimized version.

Comment: I think the way I have structured is part of the problem and I need to perhaps looking at its structure and then using r.js to minify the project...  Thanks for your input on this.